# How would I bubble sort a linked list of names?

Tags: c, string, linked-list, scanf, bubble-sort

I need help with creating a function that does a bubble sort on a linked list of names. Thanks for the help in advance.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<ctype.h>
#include<string.h>

#define MAX_STR_LEN 25

typedef struct Data_ {
    char *name;
    struct Data_ *next;
}Data;

Data* bubble_sort(Data *list);
Data* read_from_file(const char* file, const int size);
void display(Data *list);
void push(Data **head, char *name);

int main(int argc, char **argv){

    if(argc != 2){
            printf("Not enough parameters!");
            exit(0);
    }

    Data *head = NULL;

    int size = 10;
    head = read_from_file(argv[1], size);

    printf("\nBubble Sort\n");

    head = bubble_sort(head);
    display(head);
}

Data *bubble_sort(Data *list){



}
void push(Data **head, char *name){

    Data *temp = malloc(sizeof(Data*));
    temp->name = name;
    temp->next = *head;
    *head = temp;

}

Data* read_from_file(const char* file, const int size){

    FILE *input;
    input = fopen(file, "r");
    Data *new_ = (Data*)malloc(sizeof(Data*));
    new_->next = NULL;

    int i;
    char name[MAX_STR_LEN];
    for(i = 0; i < size; i++){
    fscanf(input, "%25s", &name);
    push(&new_, name);
    }

return new_;
}

void display(Data *list){

    Data *current = list;
    while(current){
            printf("\n%s", current->name);
            current = current->next;
    }
}
```

The file of names I want to read in is called names.txt and it looks like this:

Derek

Drew

Randell

Terrell

Carmen

Colin

Eddy

Pablo

Lamont

Dexter

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: 1) `Data *temp = malloc(sizeof(Data*));` --> `Data *temp = malloc(sizeof(Data));` ditto. 2) `push(&new_, name);` : name is local value.

Comment: 3)`fscanf(input, "%25s", &name);` --> `fscanf(input, "%24s", name);`

Comment: The code reads a max of 10 characters at a time, however, that is only working for the current file.  what is a name was greater than 9 characters long?

Comment: regarding this line: Data *temp = malloc(sizeof(Data*));  This always only allocates 4 bytes (the size of a pointer)  so change the line to: Data *temp = malloc(sizeof(Data)); because struct Data is 32 bytes long, the malloc needs to be 32 bytes long

Comment: regardinga this line: fscanf(input, "%25s", &name); name is already the address of the char array, so it should not have the leading '&'

Comment: regarding this line: Data *temp = malloc(sizeof(Data*)); as above, the 'Data*' should be 'Data'

Comment: regarding this line: temp->name = name; this is always setting the same address, I.E. the address, on the stack, of the name array, Therefore, there needs to be a change of either a malloc for the string to be held in or (my preference) change the definition of the struct Data to be a string array of 25 characters, init the struct char field to nulls  and add a memcpy to copy the name array to the string array in the Data struct.

Comment: If the source file is actually double spaced, then you need to check the results of each read for a zero length string and skip the call to push()

Comment: the max of 10 reads is highly undesirable as it may result in the file not being completely read (see comment on double spacing) or the next file read may have more or less lines.  Much better to read until EOF

Answer (score 1):

You need to reserve room for all those names, you can use `strdup()`:

```
void push(Data **head, char *name){
    Data *temp = malloc(sizeof(Data*));
    temp->name = strdup(name); /* here */
    temp->next = *head;
    *head = temp;
}
```

or `malloc` and `strcpy`:

```
void push(Data **head, char *name){
     Data *temp = malloc(sizeof(Data*));
     temp->name = malloc(strlen(name) + 1);
     strcpy(temp->name, name);
     temp->next = *head;
     *head = temp;
}
```

Don't forget to `free` at the end

Also note that you are passing a wrong size to `malloc`:

```
Data *temp = malloc(sizeof(Data*));
```

Must be

```
Data *temp = malloc(sizeof(Data));
```

or

```
Data *temp = malloc(sizeof(*temp));
```

If you are under some unix, valgrind and gdb are excellent tools for detect this kind of problems.